# Does jQuery show() / hide() on iPhone / Android work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, android, mobile

I've been testing a website on mobile devices which uses a simple hide() / show() on a form. Works great on the desktop but not at all on mobile devices. Does anyone know if the functions are supported?

Using jQuery 1.5

Thanks

Ric

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<strike>Okay, this is a terrible answer and thanks to everyone for their help.</strike>

In the end I combined all the JS files together. This fixed the script execution order problem on iPhone / Android. I'm not sure why it was happening on this particular site, and only on mobile phones.

<strike>It's not a very elegant solution and I do not recommend it. In my case it was for a temporary microsite so decided it was acceptable. Should I discover more about the problem I will post it here.</strike>

As Colt pointed out I was a bit rash saying it wasn't en elegant solution combining all the files together. In fact it is just what you should be doing! My frustration was that desktop and mobile browsers handled the JS different, and when developing the site I don't combine/minify the files until I know they work. Makes debugging and updating libraries easier.

As I feel bad for suggesting poor advice here's a little top tip: When on the production server I use Smart Optimizer (http://farhadi.ir/works/smartoptimizer) to handle joining, minifying, GZipping and caching the files for me. Means my dev code remains nicely seperated and it's easy to up jQuery, plugins etc but on the live site everything is nicely stuck together.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, jQuery works fine on iPhone and Android.

Comment: Incidentally, this would be pretty easy to test yourself.

Comment: I have tested it, and it's not working for me. I was specifically asking about show and hide. Just seeing if anyone had got it to work and if it was a mistake my end.

Comment: Are you testing it in an isolated fashion? i.e. stock jQuery, nothing but a single div and call to show/hide? I've used jQuery in all sorts of smartphone projects without issues. I'd guess you have a JS error somewhere.

Comment: It's a script execution order issue. Made a simple test page. That worked fine. But no matter what I do on the proper site the phone throws an error ReferenceError: can't find variable $. Tried script loaders, all sorts. Nothing works! Maybe I should do some updates, might be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

yes works fine,
I had done in many projects for smartphones (iPhone, Android) specially and works as charm

you can be sure for this, because, new mobile web framework, jQtouch, and jQuery mobile is in jQuery and alot others too.

Answer (score 0):

Ric I wouldn't say that combining all of the JS files together is really that bad of a solution, in fact I think that minifying and combining JS code is a great practice, unless you need people to be able to read your JS from source for some reason. Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I usually use SmartOptimizer to do that and cache the files automatically.Just sometimes I don't want to download everything when the hit the homepage. Maybe they get jQuery and my basic custom stuff used on 90% of pages, then a couple of pages require a lot of additional JS that most people will never need. So I separate it. My main annoyance was that all the desktop browsers worked correctly, but the mobile ones loaded/executed the scripts in a different order. When I am developing I like all my scripts separate for debugging. I'll update my answer below.